# how to access the items source of a jquery ui combox

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, combobox

i would like to be able to access the items of a jquery ui combobox from javascript. does anybody know how to access the original data items or the filtered list from within jquery?

i have found the following suggestions but cant get them to work :

```
$("combobox_selector")
.data("combobox")
.wrapper
.find("input")
.data("autocomplete")
.menu
.element;

or


$("input").autocomplete({
open: function (event, ui) {
    // menu is a jQuery object.
    var menu = $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element;
```

Comment: are you getting an error or how do you know they aren't working?

Comment: hi I  have resolved this now. originally i was trying to modify this control to fit my specifications http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290218/Custom-ASP-NET-Editable-DropDownList I have since realised it is not very good and falls apart with versions  of jquery that are not 1.6.4. i resolved the issue by passing the source list to the element in html 5 data tags, but have since realised that this is the correct solution http://www.melrosesolutions.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/7/16/Turn-SELECTs-into-Comboboxes-with-jQuery-UI-Autocomplete Thanks for your help